# Identifying which item was selected from a dynamically created form in WordPress / PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, showmodaldialog

After a better understanding of the code after some research I am now asking a further question.

I have a dynamically generated form, the code is shown below:

```
function prepareBlocksHtml_()
{
    $class = new Graffitiwall();
    $data = $class->getBlocks();

    /* Get the current orderID */
    $orderid = get_last_order_id();

    echo "The Latest Order ID is ";  
    echo $orderid;  


    $html = '<table width="100%" border="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Block</th>
      <th>OrderID</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Image</th>
      <th>Destination</th>
      <th>Expiry</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>';
    $count = 1;
    if(count($data) == 0)
    {
        return "<div class='alert alert-warning' >Your blocks are not active yet, or you have not purchased any blocks yet.</div>";
    }
    foreach($data as $block)
    {

        if($block->status == 0)
        {
            $block->status = "Pending Approval";
        }
        else
        {
            $block->status = "Active";
        }

        $fields = array();
        $fiedls['orderid'] = $block->orderid;
        $fields['destination'] = $block->destination;
        $fields['tagline'] = $block->tagline;
        $fields['image'] = $block->image;
        $fields['id'] = $block->id;

        $fields = json_encode($fields);

        $settings = $block->permissions;
        $html .= '<tr id=block_"'.$block->id.'">';

        /* add order ID PC 14-8-2018 */


        $html .= '<td>'.$count.'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$block->orderid.'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$block->status.'</td>';
        $html .= '<td><img style="max-width: 61px" class="img-responsive " src="'.$block->image.'" </td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$block->destination.'</td>';
        $html .= '<td>'.$block->expiry.'</td>';


        $html .= '<td><button class="edit" onclick="showModal(\''.$block->userid.'\',\''.base64_encode($settings).'\',\''.base64_encode($fields).'\')">Edit</button></td>';

        $html .= '</tr>';
        $count ++;

    }

    $html .='</table>';
    return $html;

}
```

The code grabs data from a table and shows a list of orders and the data associate with each one. Then the code calls a ShowModal function that sends the user and data as well for each row, with an EDIT button highlighted here:

```
$html .= '<td><button class="edit" onclick="showModal(\''.$block->userid.'\',\''.base64_encode($settings).'\',\''.base64_encode($fields).'\')">Edit</button></td>';
```

This calls a function in my main.js file called showModal as shown here

```
function showModal(user,settings,data)
{
    jQuery("#uploadBox, #selectBox, #labelurl, #url").hide();

    jQuery("#editListing").modal();

   settings = JSON.parse(atob(settings));
   data = JSON.parse(atob(data));


   if(typeof(settings.custom_logo) !== 'undefined' && settings.custom_logo === true)
   {
       jQuery("#uploadBox").show();
   }
   if(typeof(settings.badge) !== 'undefined' && settings.badge === true)
   {
       jQuery("#selectBox").show();
   }
   if(typeof(settings.link) !== 'undefined' && settings.link === true)
   {
    jQuery("#labelurl, #url").show();
   }


   // this is where data is passed to the showModal
   // add in orderid mapping to ordid

   jQuery("#ordid").val(data.orderid);

   jQuery("#url").val(data.destination);
    jQuery("#tooltip").val(data.tagline);
    jQuery("#rid").val(data.id);
    jQuery("#blockImage").attr('src',data.image);

    jQuery('#editListing').modal('show');


}
```

Then this calls the code for showing the form:

```
<div id="editListing" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Block</h4>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="editingForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                        <!-- Added label for Order ID -->
                        <label id="labelorderid" class="" style="display: none">Order ID</label>
                        <input id="ordid" name="ordid" style="display: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="Order ID" />

                        <label id="labelurl" class="" style="display: none">Destination Url with http://</label>
                        <input id="url" name="url" style="display: none;" class="form-control" placeholder="Destination URL with http://" />

                        <label class="">Strapline</label>
                        <input id="tooltip" name="tooltip" class="form-control" placeholder="Strapline" />
                        <label class="">Images</label>
                        <div id="uploadBox" class="row" style="display: none;">

                            <div class="col-lg-2">
                                <img id="blockImage" src="" class="img-responsive zoom" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                <input id="imageFile" name="imageFile" type="file" class="">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Changed the value of selection - starting at 0 instead of 1 -->

                        <div id="selectBox" class="row" style="display: none">
                            <p>Stickers are currently free to change</p>
                            <select id="stickers">
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/001.jpg' value='0'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/002.jpg' value='1'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/003.jpg' value='2'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/004.jpg' value='3'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/005.jpg' value='4'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/006.jpg' value='5'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/007.jpg' value='6'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/008.jpg' value='7'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/009.jpg' value='8'>
                                <option data-img-src='/wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/010.jpg' value='9'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/011.jpg' value='10'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/012.jpg' value='11'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/013.jpg' value='12'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/014.jpg' value='13'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/015.jpg' value='14'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/016.jpg' value='15'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/017.jpg' value='16'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/018.jpg' value='17'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/019.jpg' value='18'>
                                <option data-img-src=../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/020.jpg' value='19'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/021.jpg' value='20'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/022.jpg' value='21'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/023.jpg' value='22'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/024.jpg' value='23'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/025.jpg' value='24'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/026.jpg' value='25'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/027.jpg' value='26'>
                                <option data-img-src='../wp-content/plugins/graff/public/images/stickers/028.jpg' value='27'> 

                            </select>

                        </div>

                        <input id="rid" name="rid" type="hidden">
                    </form>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveBlockData()">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I noticed how the ShowModal function is passing parameters to the form generation code so I included the OrderID.

However the code I have added to the form to display the orderid is not working. I just copied and pasted from one of the others and modified it. It does not display the label of the input box.

How can I display the value of the OrderID correctly? If I can can get that working I can pass it to the function that updates the table.

Comment: I'll be honest, I didn't even make it half-way through this.  Any way you can try to make it a bit more focused?

Comment: Yeh, it is a lot. I am not sure how to focus it. The main question is in the prepareblocks function, there is a loop that creates a row in a table. Each row represents one of the orders.

$html .= '<td><button class="edit" onclick="showModal(\''.$block->userid.'\',\''.base64_encode($settings).'\',\''.base64_encode($fields).'\')">Edit</button></td>';

There is an edit button at the end of each row. I want to uniquely identify which button is pressed by the user, so that I know which order to save after it is edited.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the showModal function but the line seems to pass parameters to the form e.g. the current userid, and the fields. Can I pass an additional parameter referencing which EDIT button was clicked and then access the relevant orderid?

Comment: "I am not very familiar with the showModal function"  It's not a function that you wrote?  Then where is it from?  It's not a native Javascript function (not in that context, anyway).  I think seeing that function and `saveBlockData()` are probably the most important things here.  Your first two code blocks are pretty irrelevant.

Comment: The code was handed over to me by a friend because their developer walked away without a handover. Have made a lot of fixes and now trying to add this extra functionality. I am trying to understands why the ordid label/field is not displaying in the form when the other items are. The form is called from the ShowModal function that the previous developer had made and I have tried to modify to include the orderid.

Comment: `$fiedls['orderid'] = $block->orderid;`  You have a typo there.  That would be a good place to start.  I'm also not seeing anywhere that the `ordid` input element ever gets shown (it is hidden initially with `display: none;`)  It's possible I'm just missing that though.

Comment: Bugger. Thank you Patrick Q. The typo made a huge difference. From there form worked and then I was able to pass it to the update function to update the table. Thanks. It's amazing how long you can stare at something for so long and not see it.

Comment: Happens to the best of us.  Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in code due to typo.

$fiedls['orderid'] = $block->orderid;

should be

$fields['orderid'] = $block->orderid;